# Dynamically populating SELECT input with jQuery based on date

Tags: jquery, html

this is my first question asked here, seems like an amazing community.

On to the good stuff:

I'm having to populate select inputs from data contained in a set of paragraphs output by a (bad) CMS. I'm pulling the text node and attribute node from a link within the paragraph, then appending those values to different `<select>` boxes based on the year the file is from.

Here's what I'm doing:

**HTML**

```
<p class="literature-container"><a href="/url/to/file.pdf">2009-01 - Statistics</a></p>
<p class="literature-container"><a href="/url/to/file.pdf">2010-01 - Statistics</a></p>
<p class="literature-container"><a href="/url/to/file.pdf">2011-01 - Statistics</a></p>
```

**JS**

```
// Get Paragraph data

function getLitData(){

    var itemContent;
    var itemURL;
    var optionFormat;
    var fileYear;

    $('.literature-container').each(function() {
        itemContent = $(this).text();
        itemURL = $(this).find('a').attr("href");
        fileYear = itemContent.charAt(3);

        optionFormat = '<option ' + 'title="' + itemURL + '">' + itemContent + '</option>';

        if(fileYear == 9) {

            $("#statistics_literature_09").append(optionFormat);

        } else if(fileYear == 0) {

            $("#statistics_literature_10").append(optionFormat);

        } else if(fileYear == 1) {

            $("#statistics_literature_11").append(optionFormat);

        }

    });


};

getLitData();
```

This is working, but as you can imagine it's not very extensible or future-proof, as I'll have to add more `<select>` tags with the proper IDs and then edit the script next year.

My question is, how can I make this script better? I'd like to have it dynamically create the required `<select>` tag and assign it the proper ID based on the year, then append the correct files to the correct `<select>`. My JS/jQuery knowledge is too limited at this stage to wrap my head around how to do this. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you post a sample of *before* and the desired *after* mark-up? (I'm still not sure exactly what you want after looking at your demo...sorry.)

Answer (score 1):

if your give your elements and your selects an attribute called "Year":

```
<p class="literature-container" year='2011'>...
<select id="statistics_literature_09" year='2011'>
```

then in your each function you can read it and find the select that is appropriate for this item:

```
var year = $(this).attr("year");
var select = $("select[year="+year+"]");
select.append(...
```

This is the way I would implement it, you still can find your selects based on the text inside your elements, but not very reliable.

Answer (score 0):

I'd change it so that the `<select>` elements themselves are created by jQuery as well, based on the different years present in `literature-container`:

```
$('.literature-container').each(function() {
    itemContent = $(this).text();
    itemURL = $(this).find('a').attr("href");
    fileYear = itemContent.substr(0, 4);

    optionFormat = '<option ' + 'title="' + itemURL + '">' + itemContent + '</option>';

    // get the select, create it and append to body if it's not present
    var $sel = $("#statistics_literature_"+fileYear);
    if(!$sel.length) {
        $sel = $("<select id='statistics_literature_"+fileYear+"'><option value='selected'>Please Select a Statistics File:</option></select>").appendTo($('body'));
    }

    // add the option to the select
    $sel.append(optionFormat);
});
```

This way you won't have to worry about adding more selects when items from another year are added later on. Ofcourse, the selects will be created in the order the distinct years are present in the `literature-container`s, so if the order of the list changes, the order of the selects might as well...

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.literature-container a').each(function() {
    var $a = $(this);

    var text = $a.text();
    var re = /^([0-9]{4}).*- (.*?[0-9]{4})$/;
    var matches = re.exec(text);
    var year = matches[1];
    var display = matches[2];

    var $select = $('#statistics_literature_'+year);
    if ($select.length == 0) {
      $select = $('<select id="#statistics_literature_'+year+'"></select>');
      $($('body')[0]).append($select);
    }

    $option = $('<option value="'+$a.attr('href')+'">'+display+'</option>');
    $select.append($option);
});
```

Comment: I don't think `if (!$select)` will result in `false` if no matches are found for the selector, since there will still be a jQuery object returned.

Comment: @Björn: Thanks. You're right, of course, and I've corrected my answer above. I was in python mode at the time of writing that ;).